# Foreign Key Constraints Failed

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this code, I get Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
I need help on how to rectify this.
include_once('config.php');

--First Table--

```
CREATE TABLE welfare_funeral(
welfare_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(255),
Date Date,
Venue VARCHAR(255)
)ENGINE= INNODB;
```

--Second Table--

```
CREATE TABLE welfare_funeral_payees(
payee_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(255),
Amount VARCHAR(255),
welfare_id INT,
INDEX wel_id(welfare_id),
FOREIGN KEY(welfare_id) REFERENCES welfare_funeral(welfare_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

--PHP Code--

```
if(isset($_POST['record'])){
    $payeeName = $_POST['payeeName'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $welfare_id="SELECT MAX('welfare_id') FROM 'welfare_funeral'";

    $myd = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO welfare_funeral_payes(Name, Amount, welfare_id)VALUES(:upayeeName, :uamount, :uwelfare_id)');
    $myd->bindParam(':upayeeName', $payeeName);
    $myd->bindParam(':uamount', $amount);
    $myd->bindParam(':uwelfare_id', $welfare_id);

    if($myd->execute()){
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("New Welfare created");
        </script>
        <?php
    }else{
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Couln't not create Welfare");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot put a subselect as a Parameter in a prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a subselect as a Parameter in a prepared Statement.

You have to query for the id first and then you cann set these as a paramter, or write the subselect directly to the statement:

```
    $myd = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO welfare_funeral_payes(Name, Amount, welfare_id) SELECT :upayeeName,uamount, MAX(welfare_id) FROM welfare_funeral);
    $myd->bindParam(':upayeeName', $payeeName);
    $myd->bindParam(':uamount', $amount);
    $myd->bindParam(':uwelfare_id', $welfare_id);
```

Also use backticks arround column and table names not single quotes